# Do I have to pay to use certain programming languages or apis?

Tags: language-agnostic

If I were for example going to write a program in C# or a website in ASP.NET and sell it, would I have any licensing fees? For example, could I just open up Visual C# express or Visual Web developer express write a program or web page and sell it? Or would I have to buy Visual Studio? And if I have to pay to use C# and .NET for commercial use, what about Java, C++, etc...

Also, what is a guaranteed free solution if the others aren't?

Answer (score 8):

I've never known any licensing fees required for deploying C#, Java, C++, or most any other language commercially. For the languages you've named, at least, you should be totally fine.

Comment: .NET obviously requires a licenced Windows machine on which to run.

Comment: @Austin - They could use Mono, but Mono is not .NET.  Of course they could target C# & ASP.NET for Mono.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pay liscensing fees to redistrute anything written in .net... However, the user will have to have paid for their operating system liscense as it will only run on windows (or an XBox if you want to split hairs).

I was counting the minutes before some smarty came along and mentioned mono.... for the record, I wouldn't use it if I knew I needed to run on linux. Mono has issues if you want to use anything .net specific and is not a solution I'd recommend unless it's a response to having a legacy code issue.

Comment: @SLaks: Mono is not .net.  In fact, i distinctly remember seeing something on their site that explicitly said they weren't trying to be the exact same thing.  Meaning there will undoubtedly be compatibility issues, particularly with just about anything MS-specific (WPF, XNA, etc).

Comment: Yes, but you can write code in VS that will work in Mono.  No-one is forcing you to require Windows.

Comment: You can write code in VS that will work in Mono *if you take care to avoid anything .net-specific*.  I could also write C# code that compiles as Java if i stay away from all the C#-specific parts.  Thing is, if i'm writing for .net, i'm not making a conscious effort to avoid .net.  And it takes that conscious effort, particularly since there's no real line in .net between ECMA-compatible code and .net-specific code, and doubly so since Mono seems more than willing to cross that line anyway.

Comment: Yeah it's not something I'd make a habit of though. If you're going to write in c# and avoid the .net part, I'd say it would be more worthwhile just learning java. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. Unless you're planning to create a whole new language and then you'll have to pay royalties or reach some sort of patent licensing, but clearly it's not the case.
There are some specific library packages that you can buy, but you'll know upfront. Nothing that comes installed by default. You're fine

That said, if you want a "guaranteed free solution", you should go to no other place than http://www.fsf.org/

Comment: Depends on your definition of "free".  It can be convincingly argued that the GPL is just replacing one kind of fascism with another.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing, .Net platform is free including commercial use, according to Microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

In case of Java, it's another situation, Oracle bought from Sun its Java JDK which is a set of packages that makes your coding life easier and, if you want to use it Oracle claims an yearly subscription plan that include both license and support. What could be questionable are the packages developed by Sun prior acquisition and were free of charge including commercial use.

Another free option is using OpenJDK project: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK still questionable in some linking exceptions that you must be aware of and the differences between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK are more than good explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk

An interesting link I've found regarding Java: https://dwheeler.com/java-imp.html
that states also Microsoft had a website page dedicated to Java SDK but no longer exists at the moment of writing this.

The alternative to Java is C# which is property of Microsoft and is free at the moment of writing including commercial use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/
One thing is true for both, they were influenced by C++ which hopefully will remain free.

Programming languages are for free, what is questionable are the frameworks developed by different companies, some of them are free to attract more developers to use them others requires some fee.

Answer (score 0):

As Google has found out, you definitely have to pay royalties for the use of Java. See Federal court case ruling at: http://www.cafc.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/opinions-orders/13-1021.Opinion.5-7-2014.1.PDF , which states pretty clearly:
"..."The third option is the Commercial License, which is for businesses that “want to use and customize the full Java code in their commercial products and keep their code secret.”...".  Looks like Google is going to pay 8.8 billion or so dollars in fines and who knows how much for legal bills.